# Saving an NSMutableDictionary to NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

In my application one of the things I am saving is the value of a group of switches. The idea is to save the state of each switch in an NSMutableDictionary. In another method I read out the value ("state") of each switch and use that to perform a simple calculation. These switches tell me what the user has, basically.

In my data model.

```
-(void)savePlates:(NSMutableDictionary *)settingPlates {
    [self setObject:settingPlates forKey:@"plates"];
    [self synchronize];
}

-(NSMutableArray *)loadPlates {
    NSMutableArray *plates = [[self dictionaryForKey:@"plates"] mutableCopy];
    return plates;
}
```

An example of using this in the View Controller. Where 'settings' is an instance of the class that defines the methods above.

```
-(IBAction)switch55:(id)sender {
    if (self.switch55.on) {
        [self.plateSelectionDict setObject:@YES forKey:@55];
    } else {
        [self.plateSelectionDict setObject:@NO forKey:@55];
 }

    [settings savePlates:self.plateSelectionDict];

    if (DEBUG) {
        NSLog(@"%@", self.plateSelectionDict);
    }
}
```

I am crashing on this line.
    [self setObject:settingPlates forKey:@"plates"];

The error is,

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
  '*** -[Settings setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert non-property list object {
  55 = 0;
  25 = 1;
  "0.25" = 1;
  "0.5" = 1;
  "0.75" = 1;
   45 = 1;
   15 = 0;
   1 = 1;
   10 = 1;
    "2.5" = 1;
    35 = 1;
    5 = 1;
    } for key plates'
```

What is confusing is that it is spitting out the correct values, but still throwing an exception. I must be doing something terribly wrong. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All keys must be strings if you need to save it to NSUserDefaults or a plist. Your keys are numbers.

Comment: That pointed me in the direction of an answer. If saving an NSDictionary as a property, the keys have to be strings. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you uncheck my answer and select the other? The other answer is wrong. It states that your number keys are valid. They aren't. They must be strings like I stated.

Answer (score 0):

To save objects to user defaults , your objects need to be valid property list objects.
If you want to check which objects are valid property list objects, just create a new plist file and play for a while with it , add some entries and you'll see what types are already handled / available to be saved without any previous preprocessing to read/write them.
At first glance it seems your values are booleans and string / nsnumbers keys, which are valid. 
I'd suggest printing out the class of the objects and checking if all them are actually valid. 
You can get more information here 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. Right, the dict is int/double keys and bool values. Apparently the keys have to be strings to save them they way I am trying to. Good to know, although not intuitive.